# PHP Database connection error and unable to fetch database class instance

Tags: php, mysql, database, object, pdo

I'm trying to perform CRUD operation by using instance of database class I've created here(class db), but I'm not getting database connection instance into another class, I'm using Netbeans IDE and MySql Database

```
<?php
class db
{
    private $dsn="mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_stud";
    private $username="root";
    private $password='';  
    protected $connection;

    public function openConnection() 
    {
        try
        {
            $this->connection=new PDO($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password);
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   

            return $this->connection;
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            print("Error ".$ex->getMessage()."<br/>");
            die();
        }
    }

    public function closeConnection()
    {
        $this->connection=null;
    }
}
?>
```

Given below is CRUD class

```
<?php
require_once("./db6.php");
class crud
{
    public $id;#function to insert record into database
    protected $dbcon;

    public function insert($studentArr)
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO 'student' ('fname','lname','gender','batch','address','mobile'"
    . ",'age','dob','profilepic','fees') VALUES(:fname,:lname,:gender,:batch,:address"
    . ":mobile,:age,:dob,:profile,:fees)";
        $this->dbcon=new db;
        $db= $this->dbcon->openConnection();

        $result= $db->prepare($sql);
        $pdoresult=$result->execute(array(":fname"=>$fname,":lname"=>$lname,":gender"=>$gender,":batch"=>$std,":address"=>$address,
    ":mobile"=>$mobile,":age"=>$age,":dob"=>$dob,":profile"=>$profile,":fees"=>$fees));
        if($pdoresult)
        {
            $lastid=$db->lastInsertId();
            $this->id=$lastid;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing it that way, why you pass an instance of your db class to the constructor of the crud class?

Comment: For go singleton design pattern for your database else your simply creating the new connection every time, else atleast close the connection once your done with it

Comment: Title says you're getting an error: what's the error?